# How to update jquery setInterval delay while looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this basic jquery script here:

```
var delay = 200;
setInterval(function(){
  countup += 1;
  if(countup >= 50) {
     console.log('SSS');
     console.log(delay);
     delay = 10000; //Set the delay slower
  }
  console.log(countup);
},delay);
```

It does set the delay to 10000, but it dosen't update the interVal, it just keeps running at 200  ms.. Any one know what to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want dynamic timeouts, use setTimeout instead of setInterval.

```
var delay = 200;
function myInterval(){
  countup += 1;
  if(countup >= 50) {
     console.log('SSS');
     console.log(delay);
     delay = 10000; //Set the delay slower
  }
  setTimeout(myInterval, delay);
  console.log(countup);
}
setTimeout(myInterval ,delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the interval and reset it.

```
var delay = 200,
    slowDelay = 10000,
    countup = 0,
    interval;

function action(){
  countup += 1;
  if(countup >= 50) {
     console.log('SSS');
     console.log(delay);
     clearInterval(interval);
     setInterval(action,slowDelay );
  }
  console.log(countup);
}

setInterval(action,delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the delay of a `setInterval` interval, but you can use `setTimeout` instead to repeatedly set a timeout using a changing delay:

```
var delay = 200;
setTimeout(function f(){
  countup += 1;
  if(countup >= 50) {
     console.log('SSS');
     console.log(delay);
     delay = 10000;
  }
  console.log(countup);
  setTimeout(f, delay);
},delay);
```